# How can I compare two similar PHP xdebug trace files efficiently?

Tags: php, merge, compare, xdebug, trace

I have two xdebug trace files, about 25 MB each. One of them led to an error and I'm trying to find the spot where the two execution sequences deviated. The problem is that there are a bunch of irrelevant differences between the two files that I want to ignore, such as remote port numbers, query times and other database statistics.

My first attempt at solving this was to open the trace files in excel and remove the execution times which are obviously different most of the time. Then I tried using compare/merge apps to get rid of the other irrelevant differences. For example I replaced the remote portnumbers in both of the files with a placeholder string PORT_NUMBER. Some of the differences are repeated again and again so I need to be able to search and replace globally. The problem is that all of the apps I've tried are extremely slow and often crash. They can't handle rendering with word wrap, search and replace or even simple editing with files this big.

I've tried many compare/merge apps including DiffMerge, WinMerge, KDiff3, Meld, Notepad++, Eclipse and Visual Studio Code. I don't think that using diff and sed together would work, because I need to see in-line differences and jump to different parts of the large file quickly. I also would have to copy and paste the differences from diff to use in sed and they use another terminal for sed. There are also special characters and extremely long lines, so I don't think sed is a good option.

I'd like to find a way to use the trace files to find the point of deviation in the execution sequence.

Comment: If you are familiar with vim in linux terminal, you can use vimddiff that alows you to hide some columns with the cat command:
`vimdiff <(cut -c10-14,110- file1) <(cut -c10-14,110- file2)`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this, is by having two "computerized" trace files (it's `xdebug.trace_format=1`). This format is tab separated, which makes it easier to write a script that goes through them and does the comparison. You can ignore arguments to methods/functions etc too, as well as even compare return values if you wish to do so.

There is a mini script in Xdebug's contrib directory (https://github.com/xdebug/xdebug/blob/master/contrib/tracefile-analyser.php) that shows a little about how to do that.

If you can't create them again, then you are going to be up for a much harder task. The first thing I would do is to strip out all the arguments (with a regexp). VIM would probably be your best bet handling two 25MB files.